# Not able to fire onchange event dynamically from javascript after selecting options of bootstrap selectpicker

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript code to select a option on body load as shown in the snippet. This works fine for me.
The issue i am facing in the next step is that i am not able to call onchange event dynamically as soon as the value gets selected in selectpicker.

Code what i have written to select the options dynamically

```
$('select[name=pname]').val(pnamea);
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```

After this i am mapping a simple function addcname1 to onchange event which gives an alert of selected option. but this is not working for me.

Snippet has been provided which explain the problem statment more clearly.

Can you please guide me through where i am going wrong?

Thanks

```js
function openmd2(pnamea){
   
    $('select[name=pname]').val(pnamea);
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
       
    $(document).on('change','.selectpicker',function(){
        addcname1(this.options[this.selectedIndex])
    });
}
    
function addcname1(getval){
    var myname = getval.getAttribute('value');
    alert(myname)
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.3/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<body onload="openmd2('1')">
<select class="selectpicker" name="pname">
  <option value="0">select</option>
  <option value="1">Mustard</option>
  <option value="2">Ketchup</option>
  <option value="3">Relish</option>
</select>
</body>
```

Comment: it aleardy showing the alertbox with selected value

Comment: It shows when you select an option, but alert is not showing for first option and this options get selected on body onload.

Comment: what is your expected outcome? on onLoad?

Comment: As you can see on body onload i am passing 1 as the value. which is getting selected in the selectpicker. but on-change event is not getting detected so i am not able to access addcname1 function

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have to do some small changes to make it running.

```
    $(document).on('change','.selectpicker',function(){
     addcname1(this.options[this.selectedIndex])
      });

 function openmd2(pnamea){


   $('select[name=pname]').val(pnamea).change();
 }

  function addcname1(getval){
       var myname = getval.getAttribute('value');
     alert(myname)
 }
```

Here I have just changed the $('select[name=pname]').val(pnamea) with $('select[name=pname]').val(pnamea).change(); to make it running

You can refer this like to get the exact answer
https://jsfiddle.net/Sakshigargit15/j4ccdeaq/17/

Answer (score 0):

It will not give you an alert. Understand it this way.

**1-** By default, you will have value 1 selected from the first two lines of your `function openmd2(pnamea)` which will be called on your `onLoad()`.

**2-** Now in the third line, it gets a call to monitor for the `onChange` event.

```
$(document).on('change','.selectpicker',function(){
        addcname1(this.options[this.selectedIndex])
    });
```

**3-** And hence moving forward, if you change the dropdown, you will get the alert. But not the first time (your `onload`) since there are no listeners waiting for its *change*.

AFAIK, its working like you wrote it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, cant we use any other event other than change so that if the options get dynamically selected events will be triggered.

Comment: There has to be a `listener` listening for an event to give you a response. So ideally you should have a listener listening before you set your first value (default value).

Comment: Thanks got it working. I just changed my code like this $('select[name=pname]').val(pnamea).change();

Comment: Glad to know! If the answer helped you, please mark the answer as accepted. Also upvote if possible. Thanks.